# Expand a RAID50 array on Adaptec

Tags: raid, adaptec

It's possible to expand a RAID50 array on Adaptec 6805 without data loss ?

Comment: Shouldn't the question be more "Why have I chosen R50 in the first place"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAID 50 arrays cannot be expanded.  You can find complete information on RAID types and capabilities in [ASK article 15125](http://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15127).

Best Regards,
Adaptec by PMC
Technical Support